# Trying to apply "Not null" and "default" in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a column in a table in MySQL that cannot be a null value, and also has a default value. But when trying to, it just shows an error in syntax:

```
Create table example (
    code int(10),
    name varchar(20) not null default('My company')
);
```

And this is my error message:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('My company')
>   )' at line 3

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) more carefully: `data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]` - There are no parenthesis.

Comment: Please post your error message so we can see what the database is telling you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem seems to be the default part.

I have removed the parentheses and it works for me. Verified in sql fiddle here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e571a